# What is an example of the Bridge Pattern in core Java?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have read the [Bridge pattern from the GoF book](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) . Now trying to map the patterns to core java libraries but having a difficult time finding an example of the Bridge pattern . What is a example of Bridge pattern in the core java library where there is clean separation between an abstraction and its implementation?

Comment: I used the Bridge pattern exactly once, in 1997, and I've regretted it ever since.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns/

Answer (score 6):

(a) the JDBC API (a set of interfaces such as DataSource, PooledConnection, RowSet etc.) is typically considered as a bridge, which allows independent implementations for different databases (such as Sybase, Oracle or other ODBC databases) http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/servlet/ch09_02.htm;

(b) SLF4J, as hinted by its name (the Simple Logging Facade for Java), serves more as a facade than a bridge since you can still use java.util.logging, logback, log4j without SLF4J (but this is not the case for a bridge: an ODBC database can't be accessed directly without going through the JDBC interfaces);

Answer (score 5):

Here is an article that says `A Classic Example of Bridge is Drivers` - http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=29302.

And for me, classic examples of bridge (though it's not core Java) are JCL and SLF4J.